# How to use CTRL+C CTRL+V keyboard shortcuts for copy and paste in Windows Terminal

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-terminal

Is there any easy way to be able to use `CTRL+C` for copying selected text and `CTRL+V` for pasting in *Windows terminal*, just like how we use those keyboard shortcuts in notepad, word etc. `CTRL+SHIFT+C` does copy, but I wouldn't prefer that.
Hitting enter after selecting text is another way to copy in some command programs. That doesn't work either in *Windows Terminal*.

```
Windows Terminal
Version: 0.10.781.0
```

Comment: I found an article about using copy and paste in Windows cmd. Maybe it helps you: https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/how-to-windows-10-command-prompt-copy
You should enable ctrl-key shortcuts in the cmd-settings.

Comment: By Windows Terminal, I suppose you mean the command prompt? How do you know about the mention version? (I asked for the properties of C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe and got something like "10.0.18362.449", which by far does not look like your version number.

Comment: Right click to copy selected from terminal. Also right click to paste into terminal.

Comment: @Dominique No, by Windows Terminal he means Windows Terminal (`WindowsTerminal.exe`).

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version you can use the following settings:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> shortcuts are supported from Windows Terminal 1.0 in its default settings.

See https://cheatography.com/martinthogersen/cheat-sheets/windows-terminal/ for a full command list.

Comment: Only it doesn't work. Ctrl+C neither works when running PowerShell in WT nor when running `cmd.exe`. Ctrl+V works with PowerShell running in WT and `cmd.exe` standalone, but not when running `cmd.exe` in WT.

Comment: @PaulGroke It works out of the box here, I use it every day. I just tested it works with both WSL/cmd.exe/Powershell inside Windows Terminal. (I'm currently at 1.9 but it's been supported since 1.0 iirc.)

Comment: Hm. I have version 1.9.1942.0 on both my work PC and my private one. It works on my private one and doesn't on my work machine. My work machine is simply missing the appropriate entries in WT's `settings.json`. Which is strange, I certainly didn't remove them. The only explanation is that I installed WT before version 1.0 (I don't remember when I installed it, so that's possible). According to https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/968 the key bindings are only applied for new users. Existing users can simply add them themselves.